# How can I protect a java app to be deployed in the google chrome app market?

Tags: java, chrome

I'm making a java app. Is to solve a problem in engineering. I'm thinking that it would be nice to sell it as an app in the google chrome market, but I'm worried about security. I've been trying to find any info on the subject, but to no avail.

Does anybody have any thoughts on this? how secure is the google chrome market? I mean security in the sense that someone downloads your software and uses it -and distribuites it- without permission.

I would appreciate any kind of info, be it links to books or personal experiences, whatever.

Thanks!

Comment: This is one of those times where you should probably wait until you *actually have the problem* before wasting time trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

'Security' isn't really going to help you here.

You need to talk to a lawyer - most likely, you can copyright (or will by default receive copyright) the code *implementation* you have written.  Then, if you discover another person copying your code, you can serve them a Cease/Desist order, or more (depends on circumstances, I would imagine).

Preventing copying *ahead-of-time* has largely been proven to be ineffective in the long term (where 'long-term' is probably weeks to months).  This is as true for the software industry as it is for the entertainment industry.